what is the way to identify generated classes in bytebuddy transformer
We have a bytebuddy transformer we install in a javaagent something like that:
 new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(TypeMatchers.create(Configuration.getInstance()))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module, protectionDomain) -> {

                    try {
                        AnnotationDescription digmaMarkerAnnotationDescription = getDigmaMarkerAnnotationDescription();
                        return builder
                                .visit(new MemberAttributeExtension.ForMethod()
                                                                                    .annotateMethod(digmaMarkerAnnotationDescription)
                                        .on(MethodMatchers.create(typeDescription, Configuration.getInstance())));
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        Log.error("got exception in bytebuddy transformer", e);
                        return builder;
                    }

                }).installOn(inst);

and we want to skip types that are generated, we encounter generated wrappers by spring sometimes, they are not java proxies and could not find any way to identify they are generated. probably their class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() will return null but i couldn't find a way to check that with bytebuddy.
any ideas?

You can register a RawMatcher which gives access to the protection domain. All methods that accept an element matcher offer a raw matcher overload.
